# Exactly 4 digits validation in perl

Tags: regex, perl, validation, digits

I have a validation check when I pass the command line parameters to the perl program.I pass two years first passed argument should be lesser than the second passed argument and both the arguments should be only digits and also they should be exactly 4.

`#Sunny>perl check.pl 2007 2008`  This is good

`#Sunny>perl check.pl 2008 2007`  This is bad

`#Sunny>perl check.pl 200 2007`  This is bad

I have written code for this but not able to figure it out why its not working.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#check.pl

if ($#ARGV < 0) { }
else
{
  $fiscyear1 = $ARGV[0];
  $fiscyear2 = $ARGV[1];
}

if (($fiscyear1 !~ m/\d{4}/) and ($fiscyear2 !~ m/\d{4}/) and ($fiscyear1 < $fiscyear2))
{ print "Bad parameters\n"; }
else
{ print "good parameters\n"; }
```

Comment: What isn't working about it?  Which input isn't working?  What error do you get?

Comment: @agent-j check the below and you will get it.Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a bad case of overthinking things...

What you want is to verify that the arguments are two years, in the form YYYY, and that the second year comes after the first.

Well, 9999 would pass any digit check, but it is hardly a valid year. Same with 0101, or 3021, etc.

What you want is to set a given range, and make sure the arguments are numeric.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $yr1 = shift;
my $yr2 = shift || usage();

usage() unless $yr1 =~ /^\d+$/;
usage() unless $yr2 =~ /^\d+$/;

my $min_year = 1900;
my $max_year = 2200;

if ( ($yr1 < $min_year) or ($yr1 > $max_year) ) {
    die "Invalid year: $yr1";
}
if ( ($yr2 < $min_year) or ($yr2 > $max_year) ) {
    die "Invalid year: $yr2";
}
if ( $yr1 >= $yr2 ) {
    die "Invalid sequence: $yr2 is not greater than $yr1";
}

sub usage {
    die "Usage script.pl <year1> <year2>";
}
```

Comment: How do you know that 9999, 0101, and 3021 are not valid years in this case?

Comment: @friedo I don't. The OP will have to be the judge of that.

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
if (($fiscyear1 !~ m/^\d{4}$/) or ($fiscyear2 !~ m/^\d{4}$/) or ($fiscyear1 > $fiscyear2))
   { print "Bad parameters\n"; }
```

I changed the `and`s in `or`s and also the final `<` into `>` (since you want the first argument is less than the second)

EDIT:

It seems that it works in my case:

[image]

I also very strongly accept the advice of using `^$`, and have modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Even then this condition is failed                                  #sunny>perl check.pl 2005 20067

Comment: Beat me to it, but I'd also suggest changing the pattern to m/^\d{4}$/ to make sure it doesn't match years with extra digits, e.g. 20007.

Comment: @sergio thanks but the above mention doesn't work as it is taking 5 digits in the 2nd argument. perl provaperl.pl 2009 20081

Comment: this exactly will be fixed by using `^` and `$` like in my last version.

Comment: using `$` allows it to match either 4 digits or 4 digits followed by a newline; unless this is intentional, use `\z` instead

Answer (score 3):

You are missing start and end of string `^` and `$` in regexps (without them it can match 5 or more symbols):

```
use strict; use warnings;
my ($fiscyear1, $fiscyear2) = @ARGV;
if ($fiscyear1 =~ m{^\d{4}$} && $fiscyear2 =~ m{^\d{4}$} && $fiscyear1 < $fiscyear2) {
    print "good parameters\n";
} else {
    print "Bad parameters\n";
}
```

**Update**
You can also use `unless` here like:

```
unless ($fiscyear1 =~ m{^\d{4}$} && $fiscyear2 =~ m{^\d{4}$} && $fiscyear1 < $fiscyear2) {
    print "Bad parameters\n";
    exit(1); ## tells the caller side that there is an error
}
print "good parameters\n";
```

Comment: Why isn't the code working for "!~" even if i reverse the cases??          
if (($fiscyear1 !~ m{^\d{4}$}) && ($fiscyear2 !~ m{^\d{4}$}) && ($fiscyear1 < $fiscyear2))
{
    print "bad parameters\n";
} else {
    print "good parameters\n";
}

Comment: Thank you vey much. I appreciate your valuable time.

Comment: @Sunny: A and B is the reverse of (not(A) or not(B)); not (not(A) and not(B)): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Formal_proof